# Combination FlatMap and SwitchMap

Tags: rx-java2

I have specific requirement. I have subject as source ids of users. I need use id for downloading data of user. But when I receive same id of user later I need cancel old subscription (when was not finished) and subscribe new Observable. I need switchMap operator for each id, but switchMap is only for one value. And I want to downloading data of all users simultaneously (concurrency) - flatMap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupBy` to split along ids, use `switchMap` on each group when doing `flatMap`:

```
ids.groupBy(v -> v)
.flatMap(g -> g.switchMap(id -> download(id)), false, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
```

(MAX_VALUE is there in case there are more groups than the default parallelism.)

Comment: Can you show me how to apply operator ignoreElements to avoid memory leaks? Because souce of ids can be almost infinite.

Comment: What do you want to ignore?

Comment: How many items of type T are cached for key K in queue of class State? Is possible use groupBy without this caching? I have big amount of items T.

Comment: If you consume the groups properly, none is cached. However, the group keys are cached so if you have a million ids, all of them will be retained until you run out of ids. This is because the 500.000th id could be a repeat and `groupBy` can't know when to throw away an "old" group. Use `take`/`takeUntil`to limit the life of a group.